# node & express + nginx with multiple locations

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I am planning to run 2 node apps with express under one sub domain, with nginx serving the static files. In both node apps I use:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));
```

I have the following nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.domain.com;
    index index.html;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:232;
    }

    location ~ ^/(dist/|img/|app/|css/) {
        root /var/www/app/main/;
    }


    location /admin {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:233;
        rewrite ^/admin /$1 break;
    }

    location ~ ^/admin/(dist/|img/|app/|css/) {
        root /var/www/app/admin/;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }
}
```

With this setup everything is great for the 'main' app (accessed at sub.domain.com), but for the 'admin' app (sub.domain.com/admin) the same static files are served as for the 'main' app. How should I modify my setup to achieve the correct behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Check using your dev-tools to make sure that the static assets are attempting to be loaded from the correct URL; that is, `http://sub.domain.com/admin/css/` or `/admin/css/` etc. It is possible that the paths are being generated with respect to their projects root and appear as `/css/`, so when the browser tries to retrieve them, it goes to `http://sub.domain.com/css/`.

Comment: They point at http://sub.domain.com/css/, that is the issue mentioned in the question ("the same static files are served as for the 'main' app").
I'd prefer not adding configuration options in the index.html (setting base tag or similiar approaches), I would like http://sub.domain.com/admin/css/style.css to simply load the css (currently 404) as http://sub.domain.com/css/style.css does.

Answer (score 0):

I think the order of location blocks in your configuration may be the issue. For more detailed info, check out this [link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location). Try using this refactored configuration -

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name sub.domain.com;
        index index.html;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        location ~ ^/admin/(dist/|img/|app/|css/) {
            root /var/www/app/admin/;
            access_log off;
            expires max;
        }

        location /admin {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:233;
            rewrite ^/admin /$1 break;
        }

        location ~ ^/(dist/|img/|app/|css/) {
            root /var/www/app/main/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:232;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know question is old, but I have the same problem and your answer doesnt work